# How to show pop-up window on the same hwnd in masm

Tags: assembly, popup, masm, masm32, hwnd

I'm writing program on masm with showing pop-up window. How to show pop-up window?

I've tried creating window with parameters for pop-up.

This is my code:

```
WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM

  .IF uMsg==WM_DESTROY
     invoke PostQuitMessage,NULL

  .ELSEIF uMsg==WM_CREATE
     invoke CreateWindowEx, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, offset WaitingClass, offset LabelName, WS_CHILD or WS_POPUPWINDOW, 40, 70, 434, 890, hWnd, WaitingId, hInstance, NULL
     mov hwndWaiting, eax
     invoke ShowWindow, hwndWaiting, SW_SHOWDEFAULT

  .ELSE   
     invoke DefWindowProc, hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam
```

I expect the pop-up window, but it isn't showing pop-up.

Comment: `WS_CHILD` and `WS_POPUP` (which is included in `WS_POPUPWINDOW`) are mutually exclusive.

Comment: And how can I show pop-up when it's doesn't want to show